# Compare Serializable and Number

Tags: java, serialization, set

I need to remove certain objects from a list based on their id's given in another list.

So I am trying to remove `A` from `list` based on ids given in the Set `valid`.

But the code doesn't work. `Set.contains` always gives `false`, even if the id is present in `list`.

Can anyone point what is wrong with this code?

```
Class A {
Serializable id ;
public Serializable getId(){
return id; 
}

Class B{
Lsit<A> removeUnwanted(List<A> list, Set<Number> valid ){
Iterator<A> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (!valid.contains(it.next.getId())) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
return list
}
```

Comment: Please present a short but compilable code. There are typos, missing method references or brackets.

Comment: Are `list` and `pAuthorizedInstances` the same object?

Comment: i edited code . list is a object for class A , while valid is a Set of Number

Comment: Is there perhaps a type mismatch between the specific `Serializable` and `Number` objects? Things usually can't be equal if they don't have the same type.

Comment: why not make id Long or Integer and have the Set contain the same type?

Comment: No , its a requirement that id should be Serializable . Also i wrote another similar code and it is working . The only differnce i find during debug is that internally id was integer (the case when it passed) and id was BigDecimal (the case when it failed) .

Comment: I m getting BigDecimal since the value is coming from query.getResultList() in actual scenario . Any workaround for this?

Comment: Similar to what was mentioned in my previous comment, a BigDecimal can never equal to an Integer because they're of different types. You can use the methods provided in BigDecimal to convert it to int, like intValue().

Comment: Without code that compiles it is impossible to say.